# Using layout="fill" on embedded video

Tags: html, image, video, layout

I'm trying to replace an image for a video that's hosted on Wistia and I want the new video to take the same width and height as the original image. The image is taking a certain height because `layout="fill"` was applied to the HTML, but when I try to apply it to the video embedding code it just won't work.

My original code is as follows:

```
<div id="product-media-placeholder">
  <figure class="product-cover">
    <Picture src={placeholderImg} breakpoints={[675, 500, 380]} aspect={0.75} sizes="(min-width: 1536px) 675px, (min-width: 1280px) 500px, 380px" alt="Homepage Product generic representation" layout="fill" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

And I've been trying multiple approaches to get the same size for the video (with no success), and this is the one which would make more sense to me:

```
<div id="product-media-placeholder">
  <figure class="product-cover">
    <script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/videoID.jsonp" async></script><script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script><div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:133.33% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;" layout="fill"><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_u0m0klh054 videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;position:relative;width:100%">&nbsp;</div></div></div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

So, above I've basically added `layout="fill"` to Wistia's code, inside the div with the class "wistia_responsive_wrapper" - but unfortunately it's not working.

Any suggestions re: how I might make this work?

Thank you in advance!